# Why does the priest sprinkle blood before the Lord "in front of the veil of the sanctuary"?

Tags: leviticus, priestly

Leviticus 4:6 NKJV

> The priest shall dip his finger in the blood and sprinkle some of the
> blood seven times before the LORD, in **front of the veil of the
> sanctuary.**

1. What does it mean for the blood to be sprinkled "in front of the
   veil of the sanctuary"?
   Is there a locational significance? Why here?

Comment: I have narrowed the scope of this questions as I felt like I was asking too much.

Answer (score 1):

Op’s question  has to do with:

> “ What does it mean for the blood to be sprinkled 7 times in front of the veil of the sanctuary.”

> "The priest who is anointed has taken of the blood of the bullock, and has brought it into the Tent of Meeting, and the priest has dipped his finger in the blood and sprinkled of the blood seven times before the Lord, at the front of the veil of the holy place. “Leviticus 4: 5-6

> “And the priest shall dip his finger—   The different treatment of the blood is here to be noticed.  Whilst in case of the other sacrifices the priest threw the blood upon the walls of the altar of the burnt offering (Leviticus 1:5),  in the sin offering before us the high priest is first of all to dip his finger seven times in the blood and sprinkle it before the Lord.  The finger, according to the rules which were obtained during the second Temple, was that of the right hand, as the blood was taken away and sprinkled with the right hand.  Seven, being a complete number, is used for the perfect finishing of a work.  Hence the seven days of creation…” Ellicott’s commentary

These were the instructions for the Levi priests, they were only a shadow of Christ.

> “But when Christ came as high priest of the good things to come, He went through the greater and more perfect dwelling place not made with hands, that is, not of this creation.” Hebrews 9:11

The number seven symbolizes perfection, which gives us a clue that the work   is completed, finished.  God rested from all His work on the seventh day. The work  in the tabernacle has been  completed  by Christ the High priest after the order of Melchizedek, which means King of righteousness and King of Salem, which is King of peace.

> In order to bring many sons to glory, the author of their salvation had to be made perfect (7) through sufferings.  Hebrews 2:10

Becoming their High Priest involved great suffering as well.
He had to take hold of the seed of Abraham (take possession of) to become a merciful and faithful perfect Chief Priest.

> “He had to be made like His brothers in every way, so that He might become a merciful and faithful Chief Priest in the things related to God, to make propitiation for the sins of the people. For in that He has suffered, being tried, He is able to help those who are being tried.” Hebrews 2:17-18
> Here is now what I am proposing as to what the seven sprinklings of blood may mean.

While  He was clothed in the flesh, he offered prayers, supplications, with strong crying and tears to the One who could save  Him out of death and having been heard in respect to that which he feared. And even He, being a Son, learned obedience from that which He suffered.  And being perfected, (7)  He was designated, called by God  Chief Priest according to the order of Melchizedek.  Heb. 5:7-10

> Christ Himself was not of the tribe of Levi, much less a son of Aaron, should have a definite call.  Not by personal ambition, but by the call of God which involved such repugnant to flesh and blood, did Christ obtain His priesthood.  God did save Him out of death, but not from the cup.  Concordant commentary

Jesus was being prepared to be the Chief priest in the Garden of Gethsemane.

The garden of Gethsemane, a place whose name means “oil press is where the greatest battel took place inside this  son of Adam, son of Abraham.

> And being in agony, He prayed more earnestly; and His sweat became like drops of blood falling to the ground.  Luke 22:44

> And being in an agony—The Greek noun primarily describes a “conflict” or “struggle,” rather than mere physical pain.  The phenomenon described is obviously one which would have a special interest for one of Luke’s calling,  the four words he uses for “agony,”  “sweat,” more “earnestly” (literally, more intensely), are yet as a medical writer would naturally use.  The form of the expression, (better, clots) of blood,”…….From Ellicott’s commentary

> “These sufferings of Christ are not His will, but the will of His Father.  Before there had been perfect unanimity between the will of the Father and that of the Son, but in this extreme agony of soul, acquiescence gives place to submission.  From the dawn of creation, He had delighted in the will of God.  He had gladly emptied Himself of the glories of the form of the divine and took the form of a slave, and entered into the humiliation of humanity, but when it came to the death of the cross His soul revolted and His will refused to follow. Our wills are instinctive in conflict with God’s so it seems almost impossible for us to realize the awful gulf revealed in the agonizing word, “not My will, but Thine be done.”  Concordant commentary

Those drops or clots of blood represent the battel where perfect (7) submission to the Father’s will is completed.  Jesus’s conscience is cleansed from the purifying sweat from His brow mixed with blood. (blood sweat and tears).  The blood sprinkled from the right hand, the right hand of God.

The sprinkling of blood falling to the ground.

> In Barnes notes he writes, “before the vail of the sanctuary is generally understood to mean the floor of the holy place in front of the veil”
> With that being said; I think that falls in line with the blood coming out of the body of Jesus, symbolizes His  agonizing suffering  where the will of God has now been perfected in His mind,  cleansed of the struggle,  symbolizing the right hand of God, preparing  Him to be  the perfect Chief Priest to enter into the Holy of Holies.  His blood has been sprinkled before the Lord in front of the veil of the sanctuary.  Remember how the Levi priest had did his right hand in the blood of an animal and sprinkle it before he could enter the tabernacle.

To sum it all up,
The priest shall dip his finger in the blood and sprinkle some of the blood seven times before the Lord, in front of the veil of the sanctuary.  This was   a shadow of the preparation of Jesus being cleansed with His own blood that is sprinkled before He enters the true tabernacle above.

He has made Jesus ready as Chief priest to go on to complete the rest of His duties.  He has been perfected and now goes on to become the “Lamb of God” that takes away the sin of the world!

Comment: +1. You presented some great information! I must ask though: what do you mean by "Jesus’s conscience is cleansed from the purifying sweat from His brow mixed with blood."?

Comment: Going back to John 12:27 He Is saying how His soul is greatly disturbed and I think that is revealing His humanity.  Of course His soul wants nothing to do with the suffering and affliction that He knows He will have to endure in His body, He is going to be the first one to hate His own soul.  I would imagine that this is the first time He has ever experienced the such a force inside of Him that wants to go against His Father's will.  Did he experience guilt for that?  He is united to man in all of his death, and I think he is experiencing that battle.

Comment: The sweating of blood reminds me of how the life of the soul is in the blood, and how He pours out his soul to death.  He overcame the battle on behalf of man when He ends up saying not my will but your will be done. I think His conscience was cleansed on behalf of all men and the curse that Adam bore from the sweat of his brow on the Earth would be broken when the blood cleansed the ground from the curse.  I can't say for sure, but these are just some thoughts when pondering your question.

Answer (score 0):

You’re probably aware, but blood represent life. (Gen 9:4, Lev 17:11,14) Death, or anything that had come into contact with death couldn’t come close to the Tent or God’s presence. A priest couldn’t even be in the same room as his dead parents without becoming unclean.
And all sacrificial animals had to be unblemished, so an unblemished life is what is being sprinkled around.
But this life-blood is a cleanser. Is it used to cleanse and purify the altar from all contamination:sin, death, impurity.

Not sure about the significance of sprinkling with a finger, but the direction is important. When Adam and Eve were expelled from the Garden they exited to the East. The Tent is set up so that when a priest brings an offering to the Lord, they travel from East to West, essentially moving back into a garden space back into God’s presence. The curtain had seraphim (i think) stitched onto it, reminding them of the seraphim guarding the way back into the Garden.

So the whole sacrificial process can be seen as an unblemished life moving away from death, towards Life, back into God’s presence.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).